# Change the date format in C# ASP .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How should I make it readonly

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Leave.FromDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control  default-date-picker" })
```

Also is there any way to change the  following from MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Leave.TillDate" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" class="form-control datepicker" />
```

I have tried using

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

in the class but it does not work. Thanks!!

Comment: For the first part of your question try ` new { @class = "form-control  default-date-picker", readonly=true }`, for the second part does removing the 'default-date-picker' class make any difference to the output?

Comment: Sorry none of those worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see my test here,following is an example.

Class:

```
 public class Date
{   
    public Leave Leave { get; set; }
}
public class Leave
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
   
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? TillDate { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
 public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var model = new Date
        {
            Leave=new Leave
            {
                FromDate=DateTime.Now,
                TillDate=DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model Date

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Leave.FromDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control  default-date-picker" })

<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Leave.TillDate" class="form-control datepicker" />

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Leave_FromDate').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $('#Leave_TillDate').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

And if you want the first one can't be change,you can set by:

```
 $('#Leave_FromDate').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            }).attr('disabled', 'true');
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort . I used 

 $('#Leave_FromDate').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            }).attr('disabled', 'true');
and it is working perfectly for both @Html.TextBox and <input/>
Thank you!!